# ConcurrentModificationException GL2/update thread, with sync and iterators

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist, jogl

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a minor thing, but I can't figure this out. I was following all the documentations, and searched for a solution, but I'm still getting this error.

The scene is the following: 
I have a display thread (openGL), and logics update thread. Both threads are iterating thru an arraylist, which contains the child nodes. These child nodes can have other child nodes added to them. If you are familiar with the cocos2d family and it's scenegraph, it's trying to be a copy of it.

Declaration on top of the CNode class:

```
private List<CNode> m_children;
```

Allocating and creating

```
this.m_children = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<CNode>());
```

Trying to draw

```
 public void visitdraw(GL2 gl){
    synchronized(this.m_children){
        this.draw(gl);
        Iterator<CNode> it = m_children.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
        it.next().visitdraw(gl);
        }
    }
}
```

and to update

```
 public void visitupdate(){
    synchronized(this.m_children){
        this.update();
        Iterator<CNode> it = m_children.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            it.next().visitupdate();
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem occurs when I want to remove one (even if its not tested, I'm pretty sure it would raise the same exception if I wanted to add a new node runtime)

```
public void removeChild(CNode child){
    synchronized(this.m_children){
        Iterator<CNode> it = this.m_children.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            if (it.next().equals(child)){
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am fully aware that this system is not the best way to handle anything, but I'm literally forced to use this code. I just can't figure it out where the actual problem is.

Any help would be appreciated and welcomed, since for me it's kinda hard to understand why the previous developers went with this.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.m_children.remove(child)`? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thats causing the same exception.

Comment: Well, it is equivalent so it has to produce the same exception. `this.m_children = Collections.s..` happens just once in the entire lifetime of that class instance? (synchronization would fail if you change the list). Also please append the stacktrace / point out where it fails.

Comment: I'm creating the synchronized list in the constructor. 
Output I get:
   
     Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
 at com.cogwheel.engine.CNode.visitupdate(CNode.java:39)
 at com.cogwheel.engine.CNode.visitupdate(CNode.java:39)
 at com.cogwheel.engine.CWindowedScene.CUpdate(CWindowedScene.java:26)
 at com.cogwheel.framework.graphics.CScreen$1.run(CScreen.java:239)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Comment: And the exception only happens when I want to remove an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

If Im not mistaken - the Problem here is, that you have two synchronized blocks

- one for iterating
- and a second for removing elements.

Both blocks are locked only for itself. It is not the List what is locked like you might know it from DB-Recources and DB-Transactions.

So you can call two different synchronized blocks at the same time. If you do that on the same Object, you end up with to concurrent calls on the same Object.

for Example:

```
private List list 

public void synchronized read() {
   ...iterate over list
}

public void synchronized remove() {
   ... remove some elements in list
}
```

And you have two Threads A and B

Then A and B cannot call read() at the same time and A and B cannot call remove at the same time. But they can call read() and remove() at the same time.

***Solution***

Try to use java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock instead of the keyword synchronized. The Lock-Interface is new since Java 1.5 and is the modern way to do synchronization.

The following shows a class that own a buffer that will be read and changed by 3 Threads parallel:

```
class Container {

    private List<String> buffer = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
    private Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();
    private Lock readLock = lock.readLock();

    public void readBuffer() {
        readLock.lock();

        Iterator<String> it = buffer.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            it.next();
        }

        readLock.unlock();
    }

    public void addOne() {
        writeLock.lock();

        buffer.add("next");

        writeLock.unlock();
    }

    public void removeOne() {
        writeLock.lock();

        if (buffer.size() > 0) {
            buffer.remove(0);
        }

        writeLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

For testing you can remove the readLock. That will lead to a ConcurrentModificationException.
The following main() starts the test-Threads:

```
public class Concurrent {

    public static Container container = new Container();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Filler()).start();
        new Thread(new Killer()).start();
        new Thread(new Reader()).start();
    }

    static class Filler implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                container.addOne();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Killer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                container.removeOne();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Reader implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                container.readBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The point is, that you use the same LockObject *writeLock* in two methods. Additionally this kind of Lock allows it to read the Data parallel. If it is necessary to allow only one Thread at a time to read the Data you could use *ReentrantLock* instead of *ReentrantReadWriteLock*

Comment: So if I got it right, I should just mark the object for removal (like creating a flag), and actually remove it when iterating lets say before calling its update functions? So this way I could eleminate the need of having three blocks. 

I'm not sure if I understod correctly; I'm deeply sorry about that.  

Thread A should only access to the read function, and Thread B should call the read/delete functions.

Comment: Your solution would work, but I edited my answer with an idea how to solve that. I didn't try it myself, so I hope this works!

Comment: Another thing: To make shure that the unlock()-calls are always called it would be better to move that in a finally-block. I didn't do that to keep the example-code easy to read.

Comment: Thanks man, implemented the thing I wrote in my comment, and it seems to work. I'm marking your answer as the correct answer. Thanks again, tomorrow I'll try to do it with the locks. Sounds reasonable, and less messy than mine.

Comment: Could you post your results with Locks here, if you try it? Just to validate what I wrote ;-)

Comment: Its the same issue with the Reentrant locks :/ the only difference is that it wont even want to update, but crashes with concurrent modification exception. 

The unlocks are always called.

Edit: ooops, misspelled unlock, and wrote lock.. its updating, but crashes at the same point, with the same exception.

Comment: Uh.. mmmh is it possible to run visitUpdate() and removeChild() at the same time?

Comment: I just hacked a test version of it and it seems to work for me... I just had to add the fair-mode (new ReentrantLock(true)) otherwise it happend that only one of the two Threads gets access to the list for a long time. Could you post your code? Its quite late here, I will post more informations tomorrow.

Comment: Its 23:40 here as well. Will try it, thanks! Right now Im using the reentrant lock and a flag system, and its working. I mark the node as it needs to be deleted, and in the update loop thats what gonna happen. And as I can extend the flags (like this node is drawable or not) I can optimize the code by a lot.

Comment: I hacked some experimental code that reproduces the Situation. I have changed my original post with the runnable code. That version doesn't throw a ConcurrentModificationException. The Exception appears only if I remove readLock.lock() and readLock.unlock(). But maybe you have a different situation...